# Equinox p2 for an arbitrary OSGi application?

Tags: osgi, updates, equinox, p2

I am designing a software system which I think I am going to implement on an OSGi platform. It is going to be a software system running on self-service terminals. OSGi idea suits well for my demands of managing devices and end-user related functionality.
I think I am going to use Equinox as the OSGi implementation. So I came up with a question that I cannot find answer to: is it possible to setup the Equinox p2 to manage updates to my system on distributed terminals? I'd like to update lots of terminals from one place and keep track of which was updated and which was not updated and which terminal is running what version of the software system. I understand that Equinox p2 can be used to manage updates for an Eclipse RCP application but what about an arbitrary application running on the Equinox platform?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question was answered on the Eclipse Equinox forum, and thank those guys very much.
A very interesting screencast that shows the answer to my question:

[Remote provisioning with p2](http://eclipsesource.com/en/downloads/presentations/remote-provisioning-with-p2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the list, here is another [presentation](http://eclipsesource.com/en/downloads/presentations/provisioning-rcp-applications-with-p2-part-1) (in 2 parts) about using/programming against p2 by Ian Bull.